# In which template file is the create new account/log in/request new password page rendered?

Tags: theming

I would like to not render the request new password tab (/user/password), when I am not the log in page (/user). In which template file does drupal get told to render the create new account/log in/request new password page? Drupal 7, Bartik.

Comment: It does not work like this. Forms are **not built in template files**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are just menus. You can find those menus and their page callback in drupal core user module at hook_menu section.